# Working CandidatesView code on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, keyboard

I tried everything before comin' here, I swear.

But there's no way I'm gonna make this thing work without help.

Does anybody have any CandidatesView class that's actually working?

I couldn't find anything about CandidatesView in android studio website.

I created everything else in the keyboard, but this I can't manage to.

Or does anybody have some example keyboard working?

Comment: What is a `CandidatesView`? Are you asking about Custom Keyboard ? If yes then there are bunch of examples available on Git .

Comment: what you have tried so far? also what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes I am making a custom keyboard.  I just want to have some words (maybe 3) as suggestions of what the user is trying to type.

Comment: I tried to write my own class. Tried to get one from the internet. Nothing work. But if you have any example on git that worked for you please give the link.